# Best approach for Joining two datasets

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Given the below linq and lambda expressions what is the best approach for joining two datasets with multiple join conditions?  All queries produce identical results.

```
var q1 = (from t1 in table1
     from y in table2
     where t1.ColumnName == y.ColumnName
     && t1.ColumnName2 == y.ColumnName2
     select t1).ToList();

var q2 = (from t1 in table1
     join y in table2 on new { Key1 = t1.ColumnName, Key2 = t1.ColumnName2 }
     equals new { Key1 = y.ColumnName, Key2 = y.ColumnName2 }
     select t1).ToList();

var q3 = table1.Join(table2,
     t1 => new { Key1 = t1.ColumnName, Key2 = t1.ColumnName2 },
     y => new { Key1 = y.ColumnName, Key2 = y.ColumnName2 },
     (t1, y) => new { t1 }).ToList();
```

For fun I separated my queries into three unit tests. I added a stopwatch to time the execution of each test.  With the code in release each test produced the following results

Q1: Elapsed: 2500 ticks

Q2:  Elapsed: 11381 ticks

Q3: Elapsed: 2406 ticks

These results are surprising to me.  Can any one explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q2` and `q3` are identical, it is just a different syntax allowed by the compiler. `q2` is called [query syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) `q3` is called [Method Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx). The compiler coverts `q2` to `q3` automatically.

`q1` is cross join, `q2` and `q3` are INNER joins. You should use `q2` for better readability.

By the way, you can replace `q3` with :

```
var q3 = table1.Join(table2,
         t1 => new { Key1 = t1.ColumnName, Key2 = t1.ColumnName2 },
         y => new { Key1 = y.ColumnName, Key2 = y.ColumnName2 },
         (t1, y) => new { t1 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Does the cross join perform worse then the inner join.  Is the only difference in readability?

Comment: @DarthPaper Much worse. Cartesian product, you know.